# Graph with repeated/redundant edges?

Tags: graphs

Is a graph with two of the same edges a graph? 
Specifically, can this graph be considered a directed graph?

[image]

Comment: Directed multigraph is probably a correct term.

Comment: if I was asked for a directed graph and the only constraint was no self loops, do you think a directed multigraph would be acceptable?

Comment: Often when people say graph they assume no multi edges. Usually from the context you can understand what the author meant. The graphs and multi graphs, latter allowed to have multiedges i.e. several edges. They can be either directed or undirected.

Comment: I would reduce this problem by adding attribute to the edge. Say "edge weight".

Comment: _Parallel edges_ arise naturally in many contexts. See, for example, [Karger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger's_algorithm) for computing minimum cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphs, as usually defined, don't have parallel edges. Graphs with parallel edges are known as *multigraphs*.

However, like humpty dumpty, we can give a term whatever meaning we want. In some contexts, all graphs are multigraphs, and so the word *graph* denotes a multigraph. In other contexts, there are *graphs* and *graphs with parallel edges*. In yet other contexts, there are *graphs* and *multigraphs*. Only you know the conventions in your field.